# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n \sum_{j=1}^n f(j\gamma)=\int_0^1 f(x) dx $

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for every $x$. Let $\gamma$ be an irrational number. Prove that

### $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n \sum_{j=1}^n f(j\gamma)=\int_0^1 f(x) dx
$$

---

I am really stuck on this and I don't know the first step. Can anyone guide me on this please?

Comment: Wasn't there a hint given for the problem?

Comment: No this is all I'm given.

Comment: Hint: use rational approximations

Answer (score 0):

Look up
equidistribution:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence

The sequence
$\{j\gamma\}
$,
where
$\{x\}
$
is the fractional part of $x$,
is equidistributed
for any irrational $\gamma$.
This implies that
that average
converges to the integral.

The proof is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove it first for the functions $e^{i2\pi nx}, n \in \mathbb Z.$ It then follows for finite linear combinations of such exponentials, ...